# Copy a file via SCP to target but move directory structure upwards?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-server-2012-r2, scp

I need a script for my Java project (on Ubuntu) to deploy the `.jar` file to a remote windows server using `scp`.

This is what my script looks like:

```sh
scp build/libs/app.jar foo@192.68.40.41:test/
```

The `app.jar` is being copied to the Windows path `C:\Users\foo\test`. What I need is that the `.jar` file is copied to the following path: `C:\server`

I tried the following:

```sh
scp build/libs/app.jar foo@192.68.40.41:..\..\server
```

But it failed cause the script could not find the directory

I then tried to be absolute

```sh
scp build/libs/app.jar foo@192.68.40.41:c:\server
```

Same issue. What happens is that `scp` created some kind of file without file extension called `server` - omitting the `c:\` part. Still that is not really helpful and I am out of ideas how to move up the directory structure for the *target* option for `scp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a / before the drive letter :

`scp /home/ubuntu/myfile username@IP_of_windows_machine:/C:/Users/username/Desktop`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
scp build/libs/app.jar foo@192.68.40.41:/C:/server
```